# Drupal 7: how to create drop-down menu for monthly archive?

Tags: view, drupal-7, block

I'd like to be able to display a block on the right sidebar with a drop-down menu for the monthly archives ("blog post" content type). Exactly as shown in the following screenshot taken from http://curbed.com/

[image: Curbed.com - monthly archive]

Can anybody please advise me on how to do this with Drupal 7? Thanks!

Comment: Here I have added steps to do this job.


http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9340/how-to-create-a-drop-down-menu-for-monthly-archives#106053

Answer (score 0):

Use "Exposed form" from Views module.